# matrix F-norm inequalities on matrix sum and product

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, frobenius-groups

As you know, we have the two following inequalities for sum and product (for Frobenius norm):

$\|A+B\|_F\leq\|A\|_F+\|B\|_F$

and

$\|AB\|_F\leq\|A\|_F\|B\|_F$.

The question is, under which conditions, the inequalities both turn to equality.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** The Frobenius norm of a matrix is just the $2$-norm of its [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29).